# How to retrive the value from json string

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to get the value from a JSON string

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = '[{
        "StartNumber":10000000000000000001,
        "EndNumber":10000000000000100000},
        "StartNumber":30000000000000000001,
        "EndNumber":30000000000000100000}]';

    var val = eval('(' + obj + ')');

    alert("StartNumber: " + val.StartNumber[0]);
});
```

I'm not able to get the value from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

First parse the json formatted string using [`JSON.parse()`](http://goo.gl/LrlKV)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var str = '[{"StartNumber":10000000000000000001,"EndNumber":10000000000000100000},{"StartNumber":30000000000000000001,"EndNumber":30000000000000100000}]';
  var obj = JSON.parse(str);  
  alert("First StartNumber: " + obj[0].StartNumber);
});
```

**NOTE**:
One should avoid using `eval` due to following reasons mention [here](http://goo.gl/KlOUn).

Comment: I have used these but its giving not correct value  in alert First StartNumber: 10000000000000000000 might be problem in the number length how to get exact result ..

Comment: @Jain: Yes. Number length is the problem here when no. of digits exceeds 16. However, if your string is in this format '[{"StartNumber":"10000000000000000001", .... ]', then it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = '[{"StartNumber":10000000000000000001,"EndNumber":10000000000000100000},{"StartNumber":30000000000000000001,"EndNumber":30000000000000100000}]';
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);
    alert("StartNumber: " + obj[0]['StartNumber']);
});
```

- Don't use eval, useless for what it's worth.
- Tell javascript to parse your json
- Access your array starting with the index number then the key

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3hvH/)

Answer (score 0):

Its **val[0].StartNumber** not *val.StartNumber[0]*

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
val[0].StartNumber
```

or

```
val[0]["StartNumber"]
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cA5mU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I've renamed a couple of the variables to make more sense and used `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`.

```
var json = '[{"StartNumber":10000000000000000001,"EndNumber":10000000000000100000},{"StartNumber":30000000000000000001,"EndNumber":30000000000000100000}]';
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
```

Basically parsing the JSON produces an array of objects. To grab the first element:

```
console.log("StartNumber: " + arr[0].StartNumber);
```

If you wanted to loop over the array:

```
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log("StartNumber: " + arr[i].StartNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSON.parse`. If you are on old Browsers you should use a polyfill (http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).